# Mouse cursors for CHeaderCtrl

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, clistctrl

I want to find where does the MFC get mouse cursors for CHeaderCtrl when the user moves the mouse over its dividers. I've found that

```
CHeaderCtrl::OnSetCursor(pWnd, nHitTest, message);
```

always have the same values (nHitTest = 1 and message = 512) regardless of mouse cursor type is currently displaying on the screen. How can I get the resource of the mouse cursor from this code?

Comment: MFC doesn't set the cursor. It merely wraps a native [Header Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775239.aspx), which does. Why do you need to know? This sounds an awful lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/205381).

Comment: It doesn't, the message is handled by the built-in control.  In Visual Studio use File > Open > File and select c:\windows\system32\comctl32.dll.  Open the Cursor node, double-click 107 to see the splitter cursor.

Comment: The root of my problem is that I want to hide listctrl columns that user chose. For that purpose I set the column width to 0 and blocks its resizing in the notify HDN_BEGINTRACK. This is works good, but when the user move the mouse cursor over hided column he can see that it's changing to cursor with two vertical lines and two arrows directed west and east. That's why I want to get the mouse cursor with single vertical line and two arrows directed west and east and then I want to substitute standard cursor with that. Hope you understand :) @linspectable

Comment: @Hans Passant thanks, I've found it! :) But how can I use it in my case which I've described in the reply to IInspectable ?

Comment: That's a completely different question, you ought to ask it.

Comment: "Works well", not "works good".